# Exception in connecting to DB2 source using Java JDBC driver

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, db2

I am trying to connect DB2 database using java,Below the driver and connection string details i am giving,

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");

DB2DataSource db2ds = new DB2DataSource();
db2ds.setServerName("servername");
db2ds.setPortNumber(portnumber);
db2ds.setDatabaseName(databasename);
db2ds.setUser(username);
db2ds.setPassword(password);
db2ds.setSecurityMechanism(DB2BaseDataSource.ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_DATA_SECURITY);
db2ds.setDriverType(4);    
sourceConnection=db2ds.getConnection();
```

for this connection i have added the below jars

```
1)db2jcc.jar 
2)db2jcc_license_cu.jar
```

But i am getting the below error,

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException is caught when initializing EncryptionManager 'Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)'
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.x.<init>(x.java:89)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.lc(b.java:2353)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.A(b.java:1190)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.b(b.java:759)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.a(b.java:725)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.a(b.java:430)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.<init>(b.java:374)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource.getSimpleConnection(DB2DataSource.java:87)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource.getConnection(DB2DataSource.java:65)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource.getConnection(DB2DataSource.java:47)
at TestDB2.main(TestDB2.java:73)
```

I have tried different security mechanism but still i am getting the same error.the below options i have tried for security mechanism,

```
1) ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_DATA_SECURITY 
2) CLEAR_TEXT_PASSWORD_SECURITY 
3) ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD_SECURITY 
4) ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_PASSWORD_SECURITY
5)ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_SECURITY
```

And I am using JDK 1.6.0 version for developing the code

Please guide on what needs to be done for successful connection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a `SecurityProvider`. `BouncyCastleProvider` can be a good option for you. All you have to do is, as a first step in `getConnection()` method use below line:

```
 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. i am not able to add the provider in security file, so i have copied the file and paste it some other place and add the provider into security file, than i have added below piece of code in my old code    ,

 

    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

    .....

    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: And we added the security file location in the VM arguments in eclipse.

 

    -Djava.security.policy=\java.security

 

now i got the same error, so i have encrypted my password using the below code and then i have set this password into datasource. This time also i got the same error.
    "com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException is caught when initializing EncryptionManager 'Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)'"

Comment: final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    final String PROVIDER = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;
    final byte[] AES_KEY_128 = { // Hard coded for now
    78, -90, 42, 70, -5, 20, -114, 103,
    -99, -25, 76, 95, -85, 94, 57, 54};
    final byte[] IV = { // Hard coded for now
    -85, -67, -5, 88, 28, 49, 49, 85,
    114, 83, -40, 119, -65, 91, 76, 108};
    final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec =
    new SecretKeySpec(AES_KEY_128, "AES");
    final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

Comment: Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal("Password".getBytes());
    db2ds.setPassword(encrypted.toString());
Can you please guide me on how to proceed further?